# Android equivalent of textViewShouldBeginEditing

Tags: android, ios, uitextview

Is there any equivalent of `textViewShouldBeginEditing` in Android. If not how do we achieve this functionality in Android?

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you can explain what this iOS function does. Personally, I know a lot about Android but nearly nothing about iOS, so I can only guess at what you're looking for.

Comment: It fires before text view edit begins. Here we can achieve something like checking some condition before user can be allowed to type in text view. E.g. in a chat app we may block user to send any message. We can check if user is blocked before user starts typing in text view.  In iOS I'm doing it in textViewShouldBeginEditing and returning false. In this way user will never be able to type in the text view if blocked. I wanted to do the same in Android.

Answer (score 0):

```
//in your layout make change in view

    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

 //and after this in your activity check your desired condition, if condition true then 

        view.setFocusable(true);
        view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```